# Pandas: DataFrame too long after merge

Tags: python, pandas, merge

Say I have to DataFrames, one longer than the other, that I want to join on a specific column, as in the following example:

```
A = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'col2': [6, 7, 8, 9, 10], 'col3': [11, 12, 13, 14, 15]})

B = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 3, 5], 'col2': [16, 17, 18], 'col4': [19, 20, 21]})
```

Then I join them with:

```
pd.merge(A, B, on='col1', how='outer')
```

And get, as expected:

```
       col1     col2_x  col3    col2_y  col4
0       1       6       11      16      19
1       2       7       12      NaN     NaN
2       3       8       13      17      20
3       4       9       14      NaN     NaN
4       5       10      15      18      21

5 rows × 5 columns
```

However, I have two DataFrames that I'm trying to merge, with 28,011 and 15,676 rows, respectively. Merging them the same way as above, I would expect to get back a DataFrame with 28,011 rows and NaN in those cells where df2 had no observations. What happens instead is this:

```
len(pd.merge(df1, df2, on='col1', how='outer'))
  51881
```

How is this possible? The column I'm merging on is a unique identifier, and the same operation goes through without problems in Stata. What am I missing here?

Comment: You sound like you want `how='left'`?  The outer join will also include observations in df2 with no much in df1.  Also, can you double check that `col1` doesn't have duplicates?

Comment: You can get an unexpected number of rows if you merge on keys containing NaNs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you want a left join.

Try:

```
pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on='col1',right_on='col1',how='left')
```

Comment: That's what I thought as well, but, alas, no:


`len(pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on='col1',right_on='col1',how='left'))` 

gives me 51881, 

`len(pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on='col1',right_on='col1',how='inner'))`

gives 46249. There seems to be no option that merges the smaller dataframe into the larger while preserving the length of the larger one.

Comment: My bad, the column I was merging on did actually contain some duplicate values, so for exact identification I needed to merge on two columns, in the end 

`pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['col1','col2'], how='left')`

did the trick!